# What is the mean of this random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Define the following random variable $X_{n, \delta}$, for integer $n$ and $0 < \delta < 1$:

I have an urn with $n$ different balls in it.  I sample $n$ balls (with replacement), and I keep a count of how many times I pick each ball.

At the end of this process, I sort the list of object counts descendingly.  I then define $X_{n, \delta}$ to be the sum of the first $\delta \cdot n$ items of this list.

(1) Does this variable have a name already?

(2) What is its mean?  I know that the first element of the list has value roughly $\log n$ with high probability, but should I expect $X_{n, \delta}$ to have values of roughly $\delta \cdot n\log n$ or just $O(\delta \cdot n)$?

Comment: I don't understand what $\delta \cdot n$ means here. There will be at most  $n$ items in the list, so seems like a weird construction?

Comment: $0 < \delta < 1$, if that answers the question =)

Comment: You're not using the word "sample" correctly.  You draw a sample of $n$ balls; you don't draw $n$ samples.  The number $n$ is the size of the sample, not the number of samples. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Edited.